# Does gender change during reincarnation in Hinduism?

Tags: rebirth, gender

Can a man be born as woman or vice versa in their next birth?

Comment: if you think of women you will be born as a woman and vice versa...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, that means most people switch genders every birth :) because husband thinks about wife, and wife thinks about husband

Comment: @ram perhaps, that is why most people continue in this endless round of birth and death....see Gita 8.6 - "For whatever object a man thinks of at the final moment, when he leaves his body--that alone does he attain, O son of Kunti, being ever absorbed in the thought thereof."

Comment: It is possible. There is no universal rule though.